# Convert Mysql query in Codeigniter Syntax works like WHERE OR, AND Works

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I am looking for to covert this MYSQL query to Codeigniter Syntax for using in function in all.

```
SELECT * FROM `task` WHERE (status='0' AND priority='0' AND close_request='0') AND (emp_id='8' OR ass_id='8')
```

I tried but not working :

```
  $Arr1['close_request']='0';
  $Arr1['priority']='0';
  $Arr1['status']='0';

  $Arr2['emp_id']=8;
  $Arr2['ass_id']=8;

  $this->db->where($Arr1);
  $this->db->where_in($Arr2);
  $query = $this->db->get('task');
  $result = $query->result_array(); // as array
  print_r ($result);
```

Comment: what means "no working"? you have an error?

Comment: @Wisthler I got a all records, while where condition not working  $Arr2['emp_id']=8;
  $Arr2['ass_id']=8;  in codeigniter

Comment: paste error maybe?

Comment: @MusaButt  Show me all records if I am using  $this->db->where_in($Arr2);            without error so, not where condition working in codeigniter while,  this " AND (emp_id='8' OR ass_id='8') " where part working in SQL